# Save a model in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Believe it or not I'm having an extremely hard time figuring this out, I'm trying to save a model and I keep getting duplicate entry. I have a table with 2 columns `id` and `data`, `id` is **not** an auto increment column and is a primary key, here's my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TestResult extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'results';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'data'];
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Here's my controller

```
public function postIndex() {
    $id = ...

    $result = new TestResult(['id' => $id]);
    $result->results = Input::get("results");
    $result->save();

    return redirect()->action('TestController@success');
}
```

I tried just about everything to get this working with 1 query and I couldn't. I even tried building my own query using laravel's `DB` object and had an awfully unpleasant time. At this point I'm beginning to develop an attitude towards the framework since such a simple job is taking so long.

The only thing I could get to work is set `$result->exists = true`, which again needs 2 queries to determine if that is the case or not.

Can anyone *please* let me know how I can do this in one query. Much appreciation!

Comment: Well... if $id is static and a primary key in the database, obviously it'd be a duplicate entry unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Devon id is a value I'm getting from external API, the point is to update the record if it already exists, jusst like what I thought the `save()` method did.

Answer (score 1):

If `$id` exists, using `$result = new TestResult` as in an **insert** will result in a duplicate entry.

The normal way to do an **update** is using `$result = TestResult::find($id)`.

A **replace** (which I believe is what you want) can be done with `$result = TestResult::firstOrNew(['id' => $id]);`.   This would be two SQL queries, which it looks like you wanted to avoid, but it should be quick running on the primary key.